# spring framework: load all resources from classpath

Tags: java, spring, resource-loading

I have a directory in my classpath in my spring application. How do I load all files in that directory using ResouceLoader.

```
// bean for test context
public class DatabaseLoader {
    @Autowired
    protected ResourceLoader myLoader;

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        Resource[] resources = myLoader.getResource("classpath:fixtures/*.sql");
        //codepopulate in memory db with all test fixtures
        for (Resource r: resources) {
            //populate in memory db with data in this resource.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html

Comment: fateddy: any code samples?

Comment: Find the code sample as answer below. If this resolves your problem please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html) is able to load the resources using the special `classpath*:` prefix and/or internal Ant-style regular expressions. Eg. to load all resources on the classpath matching the `*.sql` suffix try the following snippet:

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver loader = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
Resource[] resources = loader.getResources("classpath:/*.sql");
for (Resource resource : resources) {
    // process resource
}
```